# Call controller function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am testing the $get method and can't seem to get it to work. I am trying to call a function within my controller (CodeIgniter) that returns just a string and then display this string in a view. The issue is that I get `[object Object]` in the place where the string `"test"` should be.. Here is the code.

**Controller** - *Public*

```
public function get_calendar(){

    return "habr";

}
```

**View**

```
//some code
calendarEvents = $.get("<?php echo site_url().'/public/get_calendar';?>");
//more code
html += calendarEvents;
//code that displays the html in my div
```

I was using the `$.get` like this before, but for the purpose of retrieving a part of a view and displaying it using this `function(data) {$( "#div" ).html(data);});` together with the GET statement.

I am looking forward to your suggestions and am very grateful for them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-and-php-variables. I think you need to echo or print the data from PHP.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your link in your question in case the external resource vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Controller

```
public function get_calendar(){
 echo "habr";
}
```

View

```
$.get("<?php echo site_url().'/public/get_calendar';?>", function( data ) {
 $( "#div" ).html( data );  
});
```

Comment: didn't work. and the bigger issue is that eventually I would be returning an array. Guess I'm gonna find another way around this. :(

Comment: nope. the div is still empty. it's like the $get request doesn't go through at all. any way to test that out?

Comment: upload more of your view i.e. the div in question. Check your error.log in the root folder also visit public/get_calendar in the browser.

Maybe changeing get_calendar to getcalendar?

Comment: I just used this in the body for testing. <div id = "testdiv"></div>
  <script>
   $.get("<?php echo site_url('<?php echo site_url().'/public/get_calendar';?>'); ?>", function( data ) {
 $( "#testdiv" ).html( data );  
});
         </script>

Comment: localhost/public/get_calendar gives blank page